# Building a ci/cd pipeline for react-native ios app: How to run expo build in gitlab-ci?

Tags: ios, react-native, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I am helping set up a gitlab ci pipeline for a react-native application that was developed with [expo](https://expo.io). Here is my `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: node/apline
cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
    - ~/.npm

stages:
  - deploy
  - tag
before_script:
  - echo $CI_BUILD_REF
  - echo $CI_PROJECT_DIR
  - apk add --no-cache bash build-base gcc git python3 curl
  - PATCH=`git log --pretty=oneline | wc -l | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//'`
  - VERSION=`cat VERSION`
  - VERSION=${VERSION%?}
  - TAG="${VERSION}${PATCH}"
  - echo "Build version = ${TAG}"

expo-build:
  stage: deploy
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - ipas/
  script:
    - sed -i "s/0.0.0/${TAG}/g" app.json
    - npm ci --production --cache .npm --prefer-offline
    - npx expo login -u $EXPO_USERNAME -p $EXPO_PASSWORD
    - EXPO_DEBUG=true npx expo build:ios --non-interactive
    - mkdir -p ipas
    - curl "$(npx expo url:ipa --non-interactive)" -o ipas/my-app-$TAG.ipa
  only:
    - master
```

What I am trying to do is have the app build a new `.ipa` every time there is a push to master. That way I can upload the `.ipa` to my mdm to distribute the application.

The problem is that if I every build a different app (I have multiple applications I am trying to do this with), it appears the build step needs to be run locally before it can be run in ci again. What I mean is that the command `npx expo build:ios --non-interactive` needs intervention in selecting the proper certificates every time I make a separate build utilizing my apple credentials.

Here is the output from a failed build (that had succeed in the pipeline before without code changes):

```
- Making sure project is set up correctly...
[17:26:33] Checking if there is a build in progress...
[17:26:34] Fetching available credentials
[17:26:38] Unable to validate distribution certificate due to insufficient Apple Credentials
[17:26:38] Unable to determine validity of Push Keys due to insufficient Apple Credentials
[17:26:38] CommandError: Input is required, but Expo CLI is in non-interactive mode.
Required input:
> Push Notifications Key (Key ID: XXX, Team ID: XXX)
>     not used by any apps
>     ✅ Currently valid on Apple's servers. 
>  Would you like to use this Push Key?
   at prompt (/expo-cli@3.17.17/src/prompt.ts:22:11)
   at CreateOrReusePushKey.open (/expo-cli@3.17.17/src/credentials/views/IosPushCredentials.ts:281:31)
   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
   at CredentialsManager.run (/expo-cli@3.17.17/src/credentials/route.ts:42:12)
   at runCredentialsManager (/expo-cli@3.17.17/src/credentials/route.ts:13:10)
   at IOSBuilder.produceCredentials (/expo-cli@3.17.17/src/commands/build/ios/IOSBuilder.ts:168:7)
   at IOSBuilder.prepareCredentials (/expo-cli@3.17.17/src/commands/build/ios/IOSBuilder.ts:124:7)
   at IOSBuilder.run (/expo-cli@3.17.17/src/commands/build/ios/IOSBuilder.ts:46:7)
   at IOSBuilder.command (/expo-cli@3.17.17/src/commands/build/BaseBuilder.ts:29:7)
   at Command.<anonymous> (/expo-cli@3.17.17/src/exp.ts:85:7) {
 code: 'NON_INTERACTIVE',
 isCommandError: true
}
[17:26:39] Failed to prepare all credentials. 
The next time you build, we will automatically use the following configuration:
[17:26:39]
[17:26:39] Project Credential Configuration:
[17:26:39]   Experience: @team/app, bundle identifier: com.app.profile
[17:26:39]     Provisioning profile (ID: XXX)
[17:26:39]     Apple Team ID: XXX,  Apple Team Name: ---------
[17:26:39]
[17:26:39]   Distribution Certificate - Certificate ID: XXX
[17:26:39]     Apple Team ID: XXX,  Apple Team Name: A Company, LLC (In-House)
[17:26:39]     used by
     @team/app, (com.app.profile)
[17:26:39] 
[17:26:39] Error
   at CredentialsManager.doQuit [as _quit] (/expo-cli@3.17.17/src/credentials/views/Select.ts:176:9)
   at CredentialsManager.run (/expo-cli@3.17.17/src/credentials/route.ts:49:42)
   at runCredentialsManager (/expo-cli@3.17.17/src/credentials/route.ts:13:10)
   at IOSBuilder.produceCredentials (/expo-cli@3.17.17/src/commands/build/ios/IOSBuilder.ts:168:7)
   at IOSBuilder.prepareCredentials (/expo-cli@3.17.17/src/commands/build/ios/IOSBuilder.ts:124:7)
   at IOSBuilder.run (/expo-cli@3.17.17/src/commands/build/ios/IOSBuilder.ts:46:7)
   at IOSBuilder.command (/expo-cli@3.17.17/src/commands/build/BaseBuilder.ts:29:7)
   at Command.<anonymous> (/expo-cli@3.17.17/src/exp.ts:85:7)
```

my question is: is this workflow supported by expo/gitlab-ci, and if so what am I doing wrong? I would like this to build reliably so I can develop a solid ci/cd pipeline for this react-native application. If there is a better process for me to follow for this use case (building and deploying a react-native ios app) I am all ears as well. Anything helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading the documentation, and talking directly with some kind folks on the expo slack. Here is the conclusion that I finally arrived at to get reliable ci builds for my react-native ios app in gitlab-ci.

Here is the build stage from my `gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
expo-build:
  stage: deploy
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - ipas/
  script:
    - sed -i "s/0.0.0/${TAG}/g" app.json
    - npm ci --prefer-offline
    - echo $P8_KEY > ${HOME}/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}.p8
    - echo $P12_DIST | base64 -d > ${HOME}/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}.p12
    - echo $PROVISIONING_PROFILE | base64 -d > ${HOME}/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}.mobileprovision
    - npx expo login -u $EXPO_USERNAME -p $EXPO_PASSWORD
    - npx expo build:ios --team-id $APPLE_TEAM_ID --push-id $PUSH_KEY_ID --dist-p12-path ${HOME}/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}.p12 --push-p8-path ${HOME}/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}.p8 --provisioning-profile-path ${HOME}/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}.mobileprovision --no-publish --non-interactive
    - mkdir -p ipas
    - curl "$(npx expo url:ipa --non-interactive)" -o ipas/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}-${TAG}.ipa
  only:
    - ci-build-test # Build api without pushing to master (protected branch)
    - master
```

Note that the build command contains all of the following flags:

```
--team-id 
--push-id
--dist-p12-path 
--push-p8-path
--provisioning-profile-path 
--no-publish 
--non-interactive
```

What is important to note is all of the environmental variables being used. Notice both my apple developer and expo account username and passwords are used:

- APPLE_ID

  - my appleid
  - used for interaction with Apple Developer portal
  - needed to log into apple from command line
- APPLE_TEAM_ID

  - The ID of my team from the Apple Developer portal
  - not explicitly used by ci command but must be in `env` with this key
- EXPO_APPLE_PASSWORD

  - application specific password generated with my appleid
  - needed to log into apple from command line
  - not explicitly used by ci command but must be in `env` with this key
- EXPO_USERNAME

  - my expo account user name
- EXPO_PASSWORD

  - password to the above user account

The following values were created after building the application through the standard build prompt `expo bi` and then obtaining the created/generated credentials with `expo fetch:ios:certs`. The binary files were then encoded into base64 before being uploaded as strings. They are also exposed as environment variables.

- P8_KEY

  - *app-name*_apns_key.p8
  - used directly in CI
- P12_DIST

  - *app-name*_dist.p12
  - encoded in base64 before uploading as env variable
- PROVISIONING_PROFILE

  - *app-name*.mobileprovision
  - encoded in base64 before uploading as env variable
- PUSH_KEY_ID

  - output by `expo fetch:ios:certs` command.
  - originally I let expo generate this when I built the app the first time.
- EXPO_IOS_DIST_P12_PASSWORD

  - From expo generated signing certificate
  - output by `expo fetch:ios:certs` command.

I hope this helps anybody having the same problems that I was!

Comment: Thanks for the clear description! Running build with the arguments I'm getting `Two-factor Authentication (6 digits code) is enabled for account: MY@account.com` and prompt to enter the 6 digits. How to I bypass that?

Comment: It turns out `If you have credentials configured for your app on your expo account there is no need to authenticate with Apple on CI` so all I have to do is have the build done on my local computer once to have expo generate the credentials for me and associate them with my expo account, log in the same expo account on CICD and run the `expo:build:ios` command with NONE of the credential related arguments, voila!

Comment: @danielsmith Where i can get documentation of these commands?

Comment: @ShriSamarth You can check the source for the cli [here](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/tree/main/packages/expo-cli/src) or reference the docs [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/expo-cli/). I ended up finding answers to my questions using the [forums](https://forums.expo.dev/)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in your credentials through build flags. For example, to pass in the distribution certificate, you will need to pass in the `--dist-p12-path` flag (see the docs [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/expo-cli/))

From your output, it looks like your push key is not associated with the app you are publishing under. Building with the `non-interactive` flag will only work if your credentials are already set for the app (ie) you've already chosen the push key to associate with your app.